# Unable to create service bus under CSP subscription using PowerShell

Tags: azure, servicebus

We have two types of Azure Subscription

1. CSP Subscription ( through re-seller)
2. Pay As You Go (Direct Subscription)

We are using following PowerShell command (using rm account) to provision Azure Service Bus:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName TestRG1  -TemplateUri
```

Using the above command, we have successfully added a new service bus under Pay As You Go subscription. But when we tried the same way under CSP subscription, we get the following error:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : - Error: Code=DisallowedProvider;
>   Message=The operation is not  permitted for namespace
>   'Microsoft.ServiceBus'"

[Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFmex.png)

What is going wrong here? Is there any limitation under CSP subscription that there is no way to provision few services like service bus etc.?

Since under CSP subscription only ARM is available and no option for service bus management, we only use PowerShell to provision services and provisioning account has all the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

From the CSP Release notes as of May 31st: •    App Service Environment to host any App Services application (including Web Apps, Logic Apps or API Apps) is not available for CSP subscriptions. This capability will become available in the future.